# workaround for clangtidy slicing warning when assigning base to derived

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Given this code:

```cpp
struct base
{
    base() = default;
    virtual ~base() = default;
    base(const base&) = default;
    base(base&&) = default;
    base& operator=(const base&) = default;
    base& operator=(base&&) = default;

    virtual void debug(){ std::cout << "base debug\n"; }
};

struct derived : public base
{
public:
    void debug() override { std::cout << "derived debug\n"; }
    void derived_only() { std::cout << "derived only\n"; }
};

derived g_d; // NOLINT
void get_base(base &b)
{
    b = g_d; // clang tidy complains about this, so, fair enough
}
```

This gives the following clang tidy warning:

[image: clang tidy warning]

But then if I assigned to a base reference first (pointers / refs are allowed to point to derived):

```cpp
void get_base(base &b)
{
    base &b_temp = g_d;
    b = b_temp;
}
```

Then the clang-tidy warning goes away.

But my question is, is this really any different to the initial code - i.e. its just masking the issue, or is this a legitimate "work-around".

Ideally I would just pass pointers/references only and not take copies. But in this case it would be convenient to use this workaround.

The warning does actually say that the overridden function `debug()` is discarded - which is exactly what we want - we only want/need the base class members.

Comment: Does using static_cast help ?

Comment: @AhmedAEK no, that gives the same clangtidy issue - and as far as I can tell, just does the same slicing

Comment: Slicing is generally unexpected, so the warning. if it is done on purpose, see how to disable the warning locally. Your workaround might be detected in future version if not explicitly marked as official workaround...

Comment: @Jarod42 I can silence that clangtidy warning no problem, but the question is, is the second implementation any different to the first? - I think your comment suggests that it is (except for the extra assignment)?

Comment: They behave identically (You might even check assembly [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bT91ec1KG) (same assembly)). (There are no extra assignment, there is initialization of an alias/reference)

Comment: @Jarod42, ah ok, thanks - so this really is just the same as the questions telling clangtidy to be quiet :)   thanks